# What is special about an amd64+mac ISO?

Tags: boot, macintosh, disk-image

Some GNU/Linux distributions (for example, Ubuntu) provide 'amd64+mac' ISOs, in addition to the regular 'amd64' ISOs. The amd64+mac ISO is apparently required for booting on certain Apple Macs. I am just curious as to what is different about the amd64+mac ISO?

Also (for bonus points ;-) ), if the amd64+mac ISO is just adding something to the regular ISO (as it appears to from the name), why not just simply make all ISOs 'amd64+mac'?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/37999/158442

Comment: @muru ok, thanks for the link. That's useful - I hadn't seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macs use a variant of EFI that doesn't play well with multi-catalog CDs, so the amd64+mac image is a 64-bit disc that uses legacy booting instead of UEFI as the normal amd64 image does.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/40480/83865)